# Converting polygons to/from raster coordinates with PostGIS

Tags: postgis

I'm looking to convert polygons from one set of imagery to a another (imageryA -> world -> imageryB) and I'm struggling to come up with an in-database solution. I have a solution in python, but we would really benefit from something that could be hooked into a trigger.

The `ST_WorldToRasterCoord`/`ST_RasterToWorldCoord` functions look like the perfect solution, but I'm having trouble getting them to work with polygons.

Right now I'm trying to use `ST_DumpPoints` to unpack the polygon but I'm having difficulty sticking the points back together as my `array_agg` causes an "aggregate function calls cannot contain set-returning function calls" error. Here's what I have so far trying to compute the world-coordinate polygon; I'm sure it's not pretty:

```
select poly_set_a.id,
       ST_MakePolygon(
           ST_MakeLine(
               array_agg(
                   ST_MakePoint(
                       ST_RasterToWorldCoordX(imagery_a.raster,ST_X((ST_DumpPoints(poly_set_a.image_geom)).geom)::int),
                       ST_RasterToWorldCoordY(imagery_a.raster,ST_Y((ST_DumpPoints(poly_set_a.image_geom)).geom)::int)
                       )
                   )
               )
           ) as world_poly
    from poly_set_a inner join imagery_a on (poly_set_a.image_id = imagery_a.id)
    where poly_set_a.id=1234;
```

Rasters seemed like a great solution but I can't find anything about using them with polygons. Maybe breaking it down into a function would be better.

Is it going to be easier to cobble the transform together from `ST_Transform` and `ST_Scale`?

Comment: I cannot understand what you mean. Can you provide a figure or an example of input and output of the process that you want to do?

Comment: Of course, sorry for the confusion. We have existing feature polygons that, due to multiple reasons, we really only have in raster coordinates. Ex: [my parking garage](https://i.imgur.com/T6FUjUQ.png) I'm looking to migrate these polygons to 4326 (my bad example code above) and eventually back down to raster coordinates in new high resolution imagery Ex: [higher resolution/translated garage](https://i.imgur.com/2x6gXZ2.png). I figure once I get raster -> world working I can figure out world -> raster.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out an `ST_Transform`/`ST_Scale` solution is embarrassingly straightforward and is probably going to be much simpler and more robust than anything that unpacks/repacks polygons. This *should* be input geom type agnostic as well.

World -> raster should be just as straightforward, though you'd need to consider how you want to handle the non-integer raster coordinates produced.

`dimensions` is the image dimensions as a Point, `bounds` is the image's coverage as a Polygon

```
select polygons.id,
    ST_AsText(
        ST_SetSRID( -- Reset SRID
            ST_Translate( -- World units to world coordinates
                ST_Scale( -- image coords to world units
                    polygons.image_geom,
                    (ST_XMax(Box2D(images.bounds)) - ST_XMin(Box2D(images.bounds))) /
                        ST_X(images.dimensions),
                    (ST_YMax(Box2D(images.bounds)) - ST_YMin(Box2D(images.bounds))) /
                        ST_Y(images.dimensions)
                    ),
                ST_XMin(Box2D(images.bounds)), ST_YMin(Box2D(images.bounds))
            ),
            ST_SRID(images.bounds)
        )
    )
from polygons inner join images on (polygons.image_id = images.id)
where polygons.id=1234;
```

And an `ST_Affine` version

```
select polygons.id,
    ST_AsText(
        ST_SetSRID(
            ST_Affine(
                polygons.image_geom,
                (ST_XMax(Box2D(images.bounds)) - ST_XMin(Box2D(images.bounds))) / ST_X(images.dimensions),
                0,
                0,
                (ST_YMax(Box2D(images.bounds)) - ST_YMin(Box2D(images.bounds))) / ST_Y(images.dimensions),
                ST_XMin(Box2D(images.bounds)),
                ST_YMin(Box2D(images.bounds))
            ),
            ST_SRID(images.bounds)
        )
    )
from polygons inner join images on (polygons.image_id = images.id)
where polygons.id=1234;
```